# Get latest message from an IObservable

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a very simple task that I would like to accomplish with rx and I am not sure how to accomplish it. Consider the code below as minimum example.

```
        var subject = new Subject<int>();

        subject.OnNext(1);
        subject.OnNext(2);

        Assert.AreEqual(2, subject.__________());
        //                        > what goes above <
```

The method should be something exposed only to the `IObservable` interface. There are two useful looking candidates that do not do what I hope. The `Latest` method will block until the next message which is not the behavior that I am looking for. The `MostRecent` documentation looked very promising but failed to deliver what I hoped for.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single method that will do it. Observables need a subscription, which can also take the form of an operator, to propagate values. You need that subscription active when the subject emits (or `OnNext`s) the values. There's nothing that caches or stores the values for you.

Here's an example using a raw subscription:

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();

int last = 0;

using (subject.Subscribe(i => last = i))
{
    subject.OnNext(1);
    subject.OnNext(2);
}
Assert.AreEqual(2, last);
```